# Query multiple tables with Servicenow Rest API and Powershell

Tags: api, powershell, servicenow

Is there a way to search/join multiple tables within one URI/call using PowerShell?

I'm trying to query the task table for any open TASK items and 'GET' back certain field values. The problem is that there are custom fields on the TASK item which are linked to other tables not on the TASK record/TASK table.

```
URI
$task = "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_task"

Adding filters to the URI
$task = "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_task?sysparm_query=yadadada"
```

..but I'm looking to be able to join multiple tables so I can "dot walk" to other tables other than sc_task.

I've been having a lot of trouble so any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: The ServiceNow Table API docs doesn't mention any such functionality, so I don't think there is a way, no

Comment: I looked and saw nothing either Mathias. I'm hoping someone will know a way on how to do this in an outside of the box fashion. Possibly something like making an SQL call from powershell.

Comment: "making an SQL call" is not going to help you - it's a REST API, not a directly exposed SQL server. Your only option is to retrieve all records from one table first, the other table separately and then implement the join logic client side

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what direction your join is (target parent, reference child vs target child, reference parent)

If you're dot-walking through reference fields on the target table, you can just do it in the query like `assigned_to.first_name=bob`, and it will automatically join `sc_task` to `sys_user` on the `assigned_to` reference field.

If you're not actually dot-walking, but rather looking to walk down into child records like if you were querying the `problem` table, but wanted to join a Related List like `related incidents` where the child `incident` table has a reference field named `problem_id` pointing back up to your target `problem` table, you could create a [Database view](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Database_Views#gsc.tab=0) joining `problem` to `incident` on `incident.problem_id = problem.sys_id`, and name it something like `problem_incidents`. Then, you can just treat that Database View like a table (as far as the REST API is concerned) like `https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/problem_incidents`